# "Reason" text box not shown to vacillating users

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

**To Replicate**:

- Click "reply" on a message in the employee inbox view.
- Choose "not interested" (Response) and "other" (Why) in the radio lists.
- Fill in the "reason" textbox.
- Change the Response choice to "interested".
- Change the Response choice back to "not interested".

**Expected result**:

- The "why" choices will be shown
- "other" will be selected
- The "reason" text box will be shown

**Actual result**:

- The "why" choices are shown
- "other" is selected.

In order to get the "reason" textbox back you have to choose a different value for "why" and  then switch back to "other".

---

This shouldn't really affect too many users, but for those of us who are indecisive it would be a boon to *not* have to make those extra two clicks. :-)

Comment: Vacillating? Don't you mean [oscillating](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166483/223030)?

Comment: Pretty sure @michaelb958 - I'm basing it on the [following definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=define:vacillate)

Comment: but I just realized that yours was a link ... and that's good too :-)

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this, so we'll get it fixed soon. Thanks for being so detailed in your report!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This bug has been fixed, thank you for your report !